# Dynamic negative binomial regression for time series

Tags: r, autoregressive-models, longitudinal

I have a count data and I need to do time series analysis using Dynamic negative binomial regression as the data has autocorrelation and Overdispersion issues. 
I did an online search for any R package that I can use but I was not able to find one.

I would appreciate any help.

An example of my data:

```
>St1
[1] 17  9 28  7 23 16 17 12 11 16 19 29  5 40 13 27 13 11 10 14 13 23 21 24  9 42 14 22 17  9

>Years
 [1] 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006
[23] 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014

>library(AER)
>library(stats)

>rd <- glm(St1 ~ Years, family = poisson)
>dispersiontest(rd) 

Overdispersion test
data:  rd
z = 2.6479, p-value = 0.00405
alternative hypothesis: true dispersion is greater than 1
sample estimates:
dispersion 
  4.305539 

#Autocorrelation
>Box.test (St1, lag=ceiling(log(length(St1))), type = "Ljung")

    Box-Ljung test

data:  St1
X-squared = 13.612, df = 4, p-value = 0.008641
```

Comment: You should probably offer a link to a methodology-oriented webpage that illustrates "dynamic binomial regression". The work "dynamic" can take on so many meanings that it is really _meaning_-_less_>

Comment: Thanks. My understanding is that dynamic negative binomial regression can account for autocorrelation and overdispersion. See this please http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1471082X14535530

Answer (score 2):

So this is basically a request to find a package (and such requests are considered off-topic). So I'm going to see if I can convert it to a question that has a coding flavor. As I said in my comment, trying to use "dynamic" as a search term is often disappointing since everybody seems to want to use the word for a bunch of disconnected purposes. Witness the functions that come up with this search from the console:

```
install.packages("sos")
sos::findFn(" dynamic negative binomial")
found 20 matches
Downloaded 20 links in 13 packages.
```

Nothing that appeared useful. But looking at your citation it appeared that all the models had an autoreggression component, so this search ....

```
sos::findFn(" autoregressive negative binomial")
found 28 matches;  retrieving 2 pages
2 
Downloaded 27 links in 16 packages.
```

Finds: ["Fitting Longitudinal Data with Negative Binomial Marginal..."](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/spass/html/fit.nb.inar1.html) and ["Generalized Linear Autoregressive Moving Average Models with..."](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/glarma/html/glarma.html). So consider this rather my answer to an "implicit question": How to do effective searching from the R console with the `sos`-package?